# Freely move imageview around page

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, imageview

i'm using Eclipse to make an android app. I'm a beginner and i'm wondering how on earth I can place an image on my page where ever I want. It keeps locking in certain places due to alignments. Surely you must be able to click the image view and drag it into the desired place??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout as a container, you can place the inner Views wherever you want. They still have to be aligned somehow, but by changing the margins they can be on every position in the parent.